# Se puede agregar una imagen en vez del marcador de google en c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

En C# yo declaro así mis marcadores de Google Maps.

```
marcador = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(tbCoordenadaY.Text,tbCoordenadaX.Text),GMarkerGoogleType.red);
```

Pero a mi me gustaría poder agregar una imagen de un auto como aparece en Uber.

Estoy usando el Nuget de GMap.Net.WindowsForms
Si alguien puede ayudarme estaría muy agradecido, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias intentar usar algo como ser

```
var point = new PointLatLng(tbCoordenadaY.Text,tbCoordenadaX.Text);

marcador = new GMarkerGoogle(point,new Bitmap("imagen1.jpg"));
```

[ADDING CLICKABLE MARKERS TO YOUR MAP (UPDATED FOR VS2015 AND GMAP.NET 1.7)](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-beginners-tutorial-adding-clickable-markers-to-your-map-updates-for-vs2015-and-gmap-1-7.html)

Quizas debas poner la imagen como resource

[add custom marker(square) to Gmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169846/add-custom-markersquare-to-gmap)

```
marcador = new GMarkerGoogle(point,new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.image1));
```

pero basicamente puedes pasarle por parametro un bitmap

Comment: Muchas gracias te lo agradezco si me funciono